# Does a round-trip from mainland China to Hong Kong count as a new entry on a Chinese L (tourist) visa?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas, hong-kong

If a French citizen currently located in [mainland China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainland_China) with a Chinese L (tourist) visa goes to Hong Kong for a short period (somewhere between a few hours to a few weeks) and comes back to mainland China, does that count as a new entry on a Chinese L (tourist) visa?

---

The question [Would China to Taiwan and back again count as another entry into China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22690/1810) only addresses the case of Taiwan, which might differ from Hong Kong, since the latter is a [special administrative regions (SAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_administrative_regions_of_China). For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_China&oldid=867954431#Entry_procedures_for_residents_of_Hong_Kong_SAR,_Macau_SAR,_and_nationals_of_the_Republic_of_China_(Taiwan)) gives some interesting differences between Taiwan and the SARs (= currently Hong Kong and Macau) in terms of entry procedures.

Comment: Yes, it does, since you're leaving the mainland China customs area.  See answer above.

Comment: @jpatokal  Thanks, since Hong Kong is a [special administrative regions (SARs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_administrative_regions_of_China), unlike Taiwan, I was hoping that the rules would be different. It might be worth keeping the two questions separate though in case special entry counting rules are introduced for SARs. Or we could broaden the other question to Taiwan + SARs.

Comment: I'd be open to another answer here, particularly if somebody can find better references.